# why am i getting this division error in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have a function in assembly that is called from my C code and it takes 3 prime numbers **p1, p2, p3**, and other 3 integers **r1, r2, r3**  where each **r1, r2, r3** integers are smaller than all of the **p1, p2, p3** primes.  Now I'm supposed to find an **n** that satisfies **n%p_i=r_i , 0< n < p1*p2*p3** for **i=1,2,3**.

Then I'm told to find this **n** by checking all of the numbers from **0** to **p1*p2*p3-1**, so I did the following:
**C code:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

extern int solve_equation(int p1, int p2, int p3, int r1, int r2, int r3); 

int main() {
int p1=3, p2=5, p3=7, rem1=1, rem2=2, rem3=3;
printf("Your integer is: %d\n", solve_equation(p1, p2, p3, rem1, rem2, rem3));

}
```

**My assembly :**

```
.MODEL small
    .STACK 100H
    .DATA
    my_mul DW ?
    .CODE
    PUBLIC _solve_equation
    _solve_equation PROC FAR
    .386
    .387
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP,SP
    MOV CX,0
    XOR AX,AX
    XOR DX,DX
    MOV AX,WORD PTR [BP+4];AX=P1
    MUL WORD PTR [BP+6];AX=P1*P2
    MUL WORD PTR [BP+8];AX=P1*P2*P3
    DEC AX
    MOV my_mul,AX;my_mul=p1*p2*p3-1
    XOR CX,CX;CX will act as n ,start n=0
    MY_LOOP:
    XOR AX,AX
    XOR DX,DX
    CMP CX,my_mul;if n went above p1*p2*p3-1 then stop looping
    JA finish
    MOV AX,CX;AX=n
    DIV WORD PTR [BP+4];divide by p1
    CMP DX,WORD PTR [bp+10];compare n%p1 with r1
    JNE continue;if not equal then continue to the next iteration 
    XOR AX,AX
    XOR DX,DX
    MOV AX,CX;AX=n
    DIV WORD PTR [BP+6];divide by p2
    CMP DX,WORD PTR [BP+12];compare n%p2 with r2
    JNE continue;if not equal then continue to the next iteration 
    XOR AX,AX
    XOR DX,DX
    MOV AX,CX;AX=n
    DIV WORD PTR [BP+8];divide n by p3
    CMP DX,WORD PTR [BP+14];compare n%p3 with r3
    JNE continue
    MOV AX,CX; I get here if I've found the said n, so I save in AX for return value before qutting the function
    JMP finish;end function 
    continue:
    INC CX;n=n+1
    JMP MY_LOOP
    finish:
    POP BP
    RET
    _solve_equation ENDP
    END
```

I keep getting divide error when I run the program.  Why is that?

Comment: Use a debugger to find out the register values. You seem to be zeroing `DX` all right, so what is left is probably a division by zero.

Comment: As Jester noted, the counter starts from zero. FWIW, [there are better algorithms to solve this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: I guess the C part calls the procedure near and the the procedure returns far. Change `_solve_equation PROC FAR` to `_solve_equation PROC`

Comment: I didn't notice that I wrote FAR ,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the procedure to NEAR fixed the problem